# Split data from mysql in jade/pug view

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug

Below code produces a list of addresses from the database which looks like something "***123 Hollywood Ave., Los Angeles, California***". However I only want to display **123 Hollywood Ave**. I've tried splitting the address using the the `split(',')` method in js but still its not doing anything and showing the normal address details

address.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    console.log(req.session.userId);
    var user = req.session.user,
        userId = req.session.userId;
    console.log(userId);
    //console.log('ddd='+userId);
    if (userId == null) {
        res.redirect("/login");
        return;
    }
    req.app.get('db').query("SELECT address FROM customer", function(err, rows, fields) {
        if (err) throw err
        var customer_list= rows;
        var address_list = [];

        for (var i = 0; i < customer_list.length; i++){
            var split = customer_list[i].split(',');
            address_list.push(split[0]);
            console.log(address_list)
        }
            res.render('fix_address', {
                address_list: address_list,
            });                
        });
     });

module.exports = router;
```

address.pug

```
extends layout

block content

  div.container
    for customer in customer_list
      li        
          = customer.address_list
```

Comment: This is a simple typo - you pass the variable `address_list` in the route but reference the variable `customer_list` in the template.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're referencing the same variable in both the route and the template.

```
res.render('fix_address', {
  address_list: address_list,
});
```

Should be:

```
res.render('fix_address', {
  customer_list: customer_list
});
```

If you want this template to render anything:

```
for customer in customer_list
  li= customer.address_list
```

Comment: I actually have something like this but using a for loop. But I keep getting error and it says that foreach is not a function

Comment: Then please edit your question with that code, otherwise it's a guessing game for us.

Comment: Done. I restarted my npm and tried the for loop, it doesnt give an error now but the updated code above shows nothing.